# How to make this type of expand/collapse more visible?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, usability-testing

I am currently developing a website where I have very limited space for a lot of information. However, it doesn't pass my tests of user experience.

How could I make this more understandable to use?

---

**1. Initial state**

[image: Initial state]

---

**2. Hover state**

*Some extra information shows up, once you click it the information expands.*

[image: Hover state]

---

**3. Clicked state** (toggle)

*The window expands/collapses*

[image: Clicked state]

Comment: Probably worthwhile keeping in mind that hover does not work for touch devices.

Comment: You're unfortunately leaving a lot of interpretation to the user. At this rate, this would then enable your users to start hovering on EVERYTHING to see what would expand and what wouldn't. If you want something to do something, be very direct about it.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the on hover state and add a clickable indication that there are more features to load on click or tap in the normal state:

[image]

(Forgive me the image being imperfect, there should not be the outline around the text, and probably there should be more white space, but I am limited to Skitch at the moment.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how an other popular (dutch) webshop does it (bol.com). Try adding a button so the user knows it can click on it.

[image]